# How to get the Maximum index count for TemplateRepeatIndex in DWT

Tags: dreamweaver, tridion, tridion-2011, dreamweaver-templates

I  have a component in tridion where its metadata design has a field called 'list' which is populated using Categories and Keywords

I used a DWT code to populate items present in the list using the following code using My DWT TBB

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Metadata.list" -->

    <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="list" --> 
        @@RenderComponentField('list',TemplateRepeatIndex)@@ ,
    <!-- TemplateEndIf -->

<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

but Im getting preview as

one,two,three,four,five,

desired output should be like:
one,two,three,four,five

so for this i need to get the maximum count of "TemplateRepeatIndex"
Is there any inbuilt function to check the same.

using Tridion-sp1,2011.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can solve this with the built in function: CollectionLength.

When you have a multi-valued text field "multiValuedField" you can find the item count using the following expression:

`@@CollectionLength("Component.Fields.multiValuedField")@@`

Collection Length receives an expression that is the fully qualified name of an item and a value selector of a package item.

The value returned is a string. When you need to perform an integer comparison or calculation you need to parse the value to an integer:

`@@parseInt(${CollectionLength("multivalued")})@@`

This works because the string between @@ and ${} is parsed as JScript.

Comment: its not a multivalued feild.Its a text field, with list of type 'Selection Box'

Comment: isn't it still a multi-valued text field? You have to select a text field, and then a list type and allow multiple values.

Comment: the CollectionLength is not working for the above field type.

Comment: I have run a test with a multi-value text field, with list type set to Select Box, and it seems to work just fine.

`<xsd:element name="muliValuedField" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="category:age">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
      <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:ExtensionXml>
      <tcm:Size xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">5</tcm:Size>
      <tcm:listtype xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">select</tcm:listtype>
    </xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>`

Comment: <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="multivalued" -->

<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond = "TemplateRepeatIndex=@@CollectionLength("multivalued")@@-1" -->
<li>
@@RenderComponentField("multivalued", TemplateRepeatIndex)@@
</li>
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->

Comment: i'm unable to get the last item in the list

Comment: @@CollectionLength("multivalued")@@ will return a string and if we subtract 1 from that string in DWT it is taking the whole as a string instead of performing subtraction,this might be the problem.How can we overcome this?

Comment: This would do it: @@parseInt(${CollectionLength("multivalued")})@@

This works because the string between @@ and ${} is parsed as JScript.

Comment: @Arjen: it might make sense to update your answer with that last snippet, so it's a bit easier to find for those that stumble upon this later.

Answer (score 6):

An easy solution would be to switch your logic around.

You can check if TemplateRepeatIndex is 0. If it is *not*, output the comma *in front* of the value.

Comment: Of course, it's obvious now you mention it - I think I've even used that approach before...

Comment: yup, thats the logic i'm currently using.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only way to do this would be to create a TBB that adds the field count as an item in the package. You would then be able to do the following:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Metadata.primary_topic" -->

<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="primary_topic" --> 
@@RenderComponentField('primary_topic',TemplateRepeatIndex)@@<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex &lt; PrimaryTopicCount"--> ,<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->

<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Comment: you mean a C# TBB. Can we take a loop in which we set a variable to count the repeatIndex and then after the end of the loop declaring another loop to get the value from the variable which gives the maximum count.

Comment: A C# Fragment or Assembly that counts the number of primary_topic values and pushes this count value to the package.

Answer (score 2):

Walter solved and explained this topic a few years ago by introducing a custom function.

http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/dreamweavercia.aspx

Don't forget to recompile his code for the current version of Tridion.

***Update***: you can find all built-in functions (and examples of their usage) that Tridion has for use in DWT on this page: http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/BuiltInFunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates

Comment: so without defining any custom functions, we cant get the maximum value count for TemplateRepeatIndex.Any poniters to inbuilt DWT functions?.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/BuiltInFunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates